# Extra undefined value in this.state

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to post a form in reactjs, and i suspect it doesnt write to DB because i get strange `undefined` in my state, which looks like:

[form looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJTeT.png)

but in console i get:

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7wtU.png)

my code on front is :

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { name: '', gender: '', email: '' };
    }

    handleChange= (event) => {
        this.setState({
          [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
          [event.target.gender]: event.target.value,
          [event.target.email]: event.target.value,
        //   [event.target.phone]: event.target.value,
        });
      }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state));
        alert('A form was submitted: ' + this.state);
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/game/contacts', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
          }).then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
          });
    
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {

        const { user } = this.props.auth;
        console.log(this.state);
        return(
            <div>
                
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>
                    Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.value} name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    
                    <label>
                    Gender:</label>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.value} name="gender" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    
                    <label>
                    Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.value} name="email" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>

            </div>
            
        );
    }
}

Dashboard.propTypes = {
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = ( state ) => ({
    auth: state.auth
});

export default connect( mapStateToProps  )( Dashboard );
```

must be super simple, but i googled for 2 hours, and could not see issue. Thanks for you time

Comment: Your `handleChange` function is wrong. 1) You wouldn't actually want to update all 3 state values every change. 2) There are no properties on the `input` elements called `gender` or `email`. **The result**: `e.target.gender` is undefined so you set the last property updated to `{undefined: e.target.value}`.

Comment: after a re render as value is not a property in state so it will be set to undefined value={this.state.value}